# Can the present continuous tense be used for emphasising things?

Tags: present-continuous

Why am I not buying any present to my girlfriend this year
Title of an article

I ve seen this sentence and I am wondering why the present continuous is used. Is it to emphasise the act of non buying or is it a kind of fixed plan because usually we buy present at Christmas

Comment: This is called the present continuous for future arrangements: https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/

Comment: I know all of that, but buying things  for Christmas can be considered as arrangement or fixed plan, seems strange for me

Comment: I see what you mean now. Yep, the use of the present continuous tense like in your example makes a statement sound more emphatic. For example: *A: Tell me her number. B: I'm not telling you anything.* The idea is that person B is not going to tell person A anything at all about her, let alone her number. It's definitely not going to happen. Does this explanation make sense to you?

Comment: Perfect this exactly the answer I was waiting for

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly right. The use of the present continuous tense such as the way it's used in your example makes a statement sound more emphatic. Take a look at the following example:

> Person A: Tell me her number!
>   Person B: You could pull out your gun and shoot me, but I'm not telling you anything. Anything at all. You hear me?

The idea here is that person B is not going to tell person A anything at all about her, let alone her number. The emphasis is in the fact that it's definitely not going to happen even if he gets killed. This is a very common way the present continuous tense is used in English. Another example:

> How much does it cost? $50,000? Oh, Mamma Mia, I'm definitely not buying it!